# Bower component: May i know how to link bower component in angular2 app

Tags: angular, bower, angular2-template

Bower component: May I know how to link bower component in angular2 app

1. bower install bootstrap
2. index.html

   ```
   <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
   ```

I am getting 404 issue

Comment: Your linking used will only work if you have the bower_components in your root folder of your public folder.

Answer (score 0):

After having executing the `bower install bootstrap` command on my side, the path you use are correct...

If you got a 404 error, this means that the bower_components folder isn't served by the HTTP server you use to serve your application.

Could you tell a bit more about the server you use and the way you use it?

Comment: in angular2 we need to do some link. i don't know how to do that. Please look this link  https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed and then try to add bower_component. Note: Please don't add bower_component inside src if u did mean it will work.

Comment: In fact, it's not mandatory to use an `src` folder as root folder. See this project: https://github.com/restlet/restlet-sample-angular2. Using this structure, you will be able to include elements from the `bower_components` folder...